# Panel wont show in the window

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to start the program with jcheckbox hat selected and rectangle visible then the Rectangle disappears when the checkbox is unselected and repainted as checkbox  is selected again. When I run the program and check the box another check box appears or left of the frame.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Head extends JPanel {

JCheckBox hat;

public Head() {
    hat = new JCheckBox("Hat");
    hat.setSelected(true);
    hat.addItemListener(new CheckSelection());

    add(hat);
}

class CheckSelection implements ItemListener {

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
        repaint();
    }
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    setForeground(Color.RED);
    g.drawOval(110, 100, 100, 100);
    g.drawOval(130, 120, 20, 15);
    g.drawOval(170, 120, 20, 15);
    g.drawLine(160, 130, 160, 160);
    g.drawOval(140, 170, 40, 15);
    if (hat.isSelected()) {
        g.drawRect(100, 90, 120, 10);
    }
    }


 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Head head = new Head();
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.add(head);
    f.setSize(400, 400);
    //f.setLayout(null);  
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You've broken the paint chain by not calling the `paintComponent`'s `super` method

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setForeground(Color.RED);
    g.drawOval(110, 100, 100, 100);
    g.drawOval(130, 120, 20, 15);
    g.drawOval(170, 120, 20, 15);
    g.drawLine(160, 130, 160, 160);
    g.drawOval(140, 170, 40, 15);
    if (hat.isSelected()) {
        g.drawRect(100, 90, 120, 10);
    } else {
        setForeground(Color.RED);
        g.drawOval(110, 100, 100, 100);
        g.drawOval(130, 120, 20, 15);
        g.drawOval(170, 120, 20, 15);
        g.drawLine(160, 130, 160, 160);
        g.drawOval(140, 170, 40, 15);
    }
}
```

The `Graphics` context is a shared resource between components, one of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to prepare the `Graphics` for painting, typically by filling it with the background color of the component.  So failing to call `super.paintComponent` means that what ever was previously painted to the `Graphics` context will still be there

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing